# For a quadratic form to minimize with a L2 regularization term, is the gradient of the solution collinear to the solution?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, regularization, ridge-regression, quadratic-form

Say you minimize a quadratic form f with a L2 regularization term (g = f + L2_term). The solution of minimizing g is x*. Is the gradient of f applied to x* collinear to x* as the figure below suggests?

I have not managed to prove it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say
$$
g(x) = f(x) + \lambda \lVert x \rVert^2
,$$
and $x^* = \arg\min g(x)$.
Then, assuming the problem is unconstrained,
we that have
$$
\nabla g(x^*)
= \nabla f(x^*) + \lambda \nabla \lVert x^* \rVert^2
= \nabla f(x^*) + 2 \lambda x^*
$$
must be zero.
Thus
$$
\nabla f(x^*) = -2 \lambda x^*
.$$
So, yes, the gradient of $f$ is antiparallel to $x$.